# Why does Debug build fails whereas Release build succeed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I went through so many topics asking about "Why does release build fail and not debug?", but I'm across a situation where it's reverse.
Here release build works fine but Debug mode build breaks.
What are possible reasons or situations where this can happen?
Any reply is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

One of our friend gave some direction towards memory freeing issue..

This is the same thing i'm facing...
When I build in release mode it build successfully, but when I try to build in debug mode it fails/breaks at a point where there is statement for freeing up the allocated memory..

code is like: check if buffer is null, and free it if it's not null...

if(buffer){
  free(buffer)
}

When I keep breakpoint on that line (inside if loop) and check value in debug mode, it appears as "bad pointer".(0x000000)

but then question remains like why it went inside of if-loop even though buffer has value 0x000000 ?

Comment: You need to post your specific error message in order for us to get a better sense of direction: there may be very many reasons for failure, that random guessing is no better than firing shots in the dark.

Comment: What do you mean by break. Easiest way is put doem code in a #ifdef DEBUG block

Comment: Captain Obvious says: "It's one of the differences between the Release and the Debug build". Usually he's right ;)

Comment: Why would it matter if Release build breaks versus Debug build breaks?  It's probably the same reasons in reverse.

Comment: If you run the Debug version in a debugger, you should be able to figure out why it breaks. Then you'll be in a much better position to ask this question. As is it's too broad.

Comment: **Semantic ambiguity**: do you mean "Debug configuration **doesn't build**" or "Debug configuration **runs incorrectly**"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the details about your environment, but some debug environments take extra steps to trigger bugs (e.g. filling `free`d memory with invalid data), whereas the release build does not, giving you more chances to get lucky.

The problem is that your luck tends to run out when you move up from test data into a real environment....

Comment: This is a good list of possible problems with a debug vs release executable, but doesn't explain build failures.  The question says "the build breaks".

Comment: @BenVoigt, the phrasing in the question can be interpreted both ways. "Debug build" vs. "Release build". It needs to be clarified. I would hope a build failure would include an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that if you are using visual studio, probably you have different configurations (linker, libraries, paths, etc.) for different profiles: Debug, Release. In general this IDE, like Visual Studio, come with this type of GUI configuration for those modes.